# Validation does not displayed

Tags: php, html

Help. Im trying to do validation for the registration code with PHP but it doesn't displayed.

here is my code for the registration form (register.php):

here is the validation, I write it before the

```
<?php
    $name_error = "";
    $pass_error = "";
    $email_error = "";
    $pass_error = "";
    $pass2_error = "";

    //validation
    if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
        if(empty($_POST["first-name"] || $_POST["last-name"])) {
            $name_error = "Please enter your name.";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
            $email_error = "Please enter the email";
        }

        if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
             $pass_error = "Please enter your password";
        }

        if(empty($_POST['password2'])) {
            $pass2_error = "Please enter to confirm your password";
        }

        if( $_POST['password2'] != $_POST['password']){
            $pass2_error = "The confirm password are incorrect!";
        }
        else{
            header("location:registered.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

and here is the form code:

```
<main>
        <div class="register-header d-flex flex-column align-items-center py-5">
            <h1 class="font-rale text-dark gray-bg">
                Sign up
            </h1>
        </div>
        <form method="post" class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center py-5">
            <div class="my-2">
                <input type="text" class="name-input mx-1 p-2 border rounded" name="first-name"
                    placeholder="First name">
                <input type="text" class="name-input mx-1 p-2 border rounded" name="last-name" placeholder="Last name">
            </div>
            <p class="text-center py-2 error"><?php echo $name_error;?></p>

            <div class="my-2 p-1">
                <input type="email" class="p-2 border rounded" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
            </div>
            <p class="text-center py-2 error"><?php echo $email_error;?></p>

            <div class="my-2 p-1">
                <input type="password" class="p-2 border rounded" name="password" placeholder="Your password">
            </div>
            <p class="text-center py-2 error"><?php echo $pass_error;?></p>

            <div class="my-2 p-1">
                <input type="password2" class="p-2 border rounded" placeholder="Confirm password">
            </div>
            <p class="text-center py-2 error"><?php echo $pass2_error;?></p>

            <div class="my-2 p-1">
                <input type="text" class="p-2 border rounded" name="contact" placeholder="Phone number (Optional)">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" name="register" class="my-3 px-3 py-2 text-light rounded border-0 form-button">Register</button>
            <p>One of us? <a href="login.html" class="text-decoration-none">Sign in</a> here.</p>
        </form>
    </main>
```

I have set all the errors to display under the div of each input.

and when I try to leave all input to be empty to test the validation. it doesn't work at all and I just head to the registered.php. Why the validation isn't displayed? Please help..

Comment: You create a variable with error but doesn't echo/return it.

Comment: `$_POST['password2'] != $_POST['password']` is the only check that avoids sending the user to `registered.php` - shouldn't this happen solely when not a single error is found?

Comment: If both `password2` and `password` are empty the condition of your last `if` statement is false, so the code in the `else` clause is executed -> you are redirected.

Comment: so do I only need to separate the $_POST['password2'] != $_POST['password'] from there?

Comment: Please read the [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions. Pay particular attention to the page on [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add some flag like:

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    
    $flag_names = $flag_email = $flag_password = $flag_password2 = $flag_passwordmatch = true;
    if(empty($_POST["first-name"] || $_POST["last-name"])) {
        $name_error = "Please enter your name.";
        $flag_names = false;
    }
    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $email_error = "Please enter the email";
        $flag_email = false;
    }

    if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
         $pass_error = "Please enter your password";
         $flag_password = false;
    }

    if(empty($_POST['password2'])) {
        $pass2_error = "Please enter to confirm your password";
        $flag_password2 = false;
    }

    if( $_POST['password2'] !== $_POST['password']){
        $pass2_error = "The confirm password are incorrect!";
        $flag_passwordmatch = false;
    }
    if($flag_names && $flag_email && $flag_password && $flag_password2 && $flag_passwordmatch){
        //Well I suppose if everything its ok then redirects to this page.
        header("location:registered.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it, thanks

Comment: The validation, but now the post doesn't insert the values...